# 3 way left join query error

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure this one out.
I have a 2 way left join query working perfectly:

```
'SELECT f.user_id, u.avatar
    FROM following AS f
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.username = f.user_id
    WHERE f.follower_id = "'.$u.'"';
```

Which is pulling a list of members 'following' you from a twitter like table, then adding their avatar from  a separate members table.

Now I'm trying to pull all the data from a third table (the actual tweets), but it doesn't work:

```
'SELECT f.user_id, u.avatar, p.*
    FROM following AS f
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.username = f.user_id
    WHERE f.follower_id = "'.$u.'"      
    LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON p.username = u.username';
```

I have also tried adding:

```
WHERE p.username = "'.$u.'"';
```

to the end, but it doesn't make a difference.  The error just says there is a SQL syntax error on the second left join.
Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` is part of the `from` clause.  The `where` clause follows the `from`:

```
SELECT f.user_id, u.avatar, p.*
FROM following AS f
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.username = f.user_id
LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON p.username = u.username
WHERE f.follower_id = "'.$u.'"    ;
```

Comment: beat my by 10 secs! +1 to you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the where condition after joins like this:

```
'SELECT f.user_id, u.avatar, p.*
    FROM following AS f
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.username = f.user_id

    LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON p.username = u.username  WHERE f.follower_id = "'.$u.'"     ' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the WHERE clause to be after the last LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT f.user_id, u.avatar, p.*
FROM following AS f
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.username = f.user_id    
LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON p.username = u.username
WHERE f.follower_id = "'.$u.'";
```

Also, for security reasons you probably want to use a prepared statement instead of concatenating the $u directly in to the query.